# how to do only this div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container"> 
  <div class="slides"> 
    <div class="slides_container"> 
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </div> 
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a> 
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
  </div> 
</div> 

<div id="container"> 
  <div class="slides"> 
    <div class="slides_container"> 
      <p>1</p>
    </div> 
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a> 
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
var n = $(".slides_container > p").length;

if (n == 1) {
    $(".prev", ".next").hide();
} else {
    $(".prev", ".next").show();
}
```

---

If "P" = 1 , i will hide .prev & .next (ONLY THIS DIV)

HOW TO ? THANKS :D

Comment: You have reused the same id="container" which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate over each group of slides, and toggle the visibility of the prev and next links depending on how many p elements are present.

```
$('div.slides').each(function() {
    $('.prev,.next', this).toggle(
        $('.slides_container > p', this).size() > 1
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the comma to specify [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and wrap them all in single/double quotes together:

```
if (n > 0) {
    $(".prev, .next", $('#container ')).hide();
}
else {
    $(".prev, .next", $('#container ')).show();
}
```

Comment: I think the poster wanted code to hide the prev/next links only when the associated container has one element. This will hide all prev/next links.

Comment: I agree the question was somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @l2aelba: I have updated the code. Now it would hide prev next links only inside the element with id `container` :)